# I want to save data in excel file using java but each time it replaces previous data. I am using javafx for building desktop application

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
try {
    FileInputStream fIPS = new FileInputStream("excel.xls"); //Read the spreadsheet that needs to be updated
    HSSFWorkbook wb;
    HSSFSheet worksheet;
    if (fIPS.available() >= 512) {
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fIPS); //If there is already data in a workbook
        worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    } else {
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook();    //if the workbook was just created
        worksheet = wb.createSheet("Data");
    }
    //Access the worksheet, so that we can update / modify it


    Row row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);
    //0 = row number
    // int r = row1.getRowNum();
    int i = 0;
    Cell c = row1.getCell(i);
    while (!(c == null || c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)) {   //cell is empty
        i++;
        //   r++;
        c = row1.getCell(i);
    }
    Row rowx;

    int x = 0;
    for (CompletenessModel s : find()) {
        rowx = worksheet.createRow(x);

        // int rx = rowx.getRowNum();
        Cell cellx = rowx.createCell(i);   //0 = column number
        cellx.setCellValue(s.getDot());
        x++;
        //rx++;
    }


    fIPS.close(); //Close the InputStream
    FileOutputStream output_file = new
            FileOutputStream("test.xls");//Open FileOutputStream to write updates
    wb.write(output_file); //write changes
    output_file.close();  //close the stream

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code only modify the row 0 data. I want to be to add as many record as possible. The user input is in javafx textarea field. I am using list for getting all the user input. I have tried many things but in vain. user input is getting in the system and is also displaying but one record at a time. When i close the application or rewrite input again the previous stored data in excel file is deleted and new data is written there.

Comment: It seems your code is incomplete, what is the definition of `CompletenessModel` and `find` method?

Comment: `available()` is not a valid way of obtaining the size of a stream. See the Javadoc.

Comment: public List<CompletenessModel> find() {
        try {
            List<CompletenessModel> listCompletness = new ArrayList<>();


                listCompletness.add(new CompletenessModel(numberOfMissingClauses,dot));




            return listCompletness;

Comment: This is the find function just using constructor of a class named completenessmodel.